# How to use Internal API's

Tags: android

I want to use com.android.internal.telephony API's in my project, For that I downloaded "framework_intermediates-classes-full-debug.jar" and added to my project. I am able to import Call.java class but not CallManager.java class. I think I downloaded older version of jar file which does't included CallManager class. then Where I get new version of this jar file which includes CallManager class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've read this article about internal and hidden methods. Maybe if you read it then you'll get the answer. http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Hi Yury, This url is not opening

Comment: It's very strange. I can open it.

Comment: No sir/madam  its not opening in my PC, anywayz thanks a lot :):). can you tell me any other solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am able to import internal API's :):)

Comment: please tell me in detail. I am also looking for using same Telophony API